# Check for time interval flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I intend running a query if the user's time is between 10am and 4pm. I know I can get current dateTime with `DateTime.now()` in flutter. How do i get to know if the user's time interval is between say 10pm to 4pm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.isAfter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/isAfter.html),  [`DateTime.isBefore`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/isBefore.html), or [`DateTime.compareTo`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html) to compare `DateTime` objects.

However, personally I'd use the `DateTime` extensions from [`package:basics`](https://pub.dev/packages/basics) which makes code more readable than using `.compareTo`, and unlike `.isBefore`/`.isAfter`, makes it easier to have inclusive endpoints for your time interval:

```dart
import 'package:basics/date_time_basics.dart';

void main() {
   var now = DateTime.now();
   var startTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 22); // 10 PM today
   var endTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 16); // 4 PM today

   // Note that since your desired time spans midnight, startTime > endTime
   // and we use || where we'd normally use &&.
   if (now >= startTime || now <= endTime) {
     print('Between 10 PM and 4 PM');
   } else {
     print('Outside of 10 PM and 4 PM');
   }
}
```

(Disclosure: I worked on the `DateTime` extensions to `package:basics`.)

Comment: what does the 20 and 16 int values do?

Comment: Oops, 20 was a typo.  I meant 22 for 10 PM.  4 PM and 10 PM on a 24 hour clock are 16 hours and 22 hours respectively.

Comment: i get this error: The operator '>=' isn't defined for the type 'DateTime'.

Comment: so what am doing is converting to microseconds before the comparison

Comment: As I mentioned, you'd need to import `package:basics/date_time_basics.dart` to get `>=` and `<=` for `DateTime`.  Comparing microseconds is fine too.